# Adding a row to a column with the sum of the values from that column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want my code to return me blanks on the continent column whenever continent is different from the country and on the end of the table I want it to show me the total of bellow 45 yo in each continent, the total of above 45 yo in each continent and the total of habitants in each continent like in the example bellow:

```
Continent | Country  | Bellow 45 yo | Above 45 yo | Total Habitants
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Europe    | Europe   |      1       |      1      |       2 
          | England  |      0       |      1      |       1 
          | Portugal |      1       |      0      |       1 
NA        | NA       |      2       |      1      |       3 
          | Canada   |      0       |      1      |       1 
          | USA      |      2       |      0      |       2 
Total     | Total    |      3       |      2      |       5
```

I'm trying this code

```
SELECT t1.continent as Continent,
       COALESCE(t1.country, t1.continent) as Country,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.age < 45 THEN 1 END) AS under_45,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.age > 45 THEN 1 END) AS over_45,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.age > 45 or t2.age > 45 THEN 1 END) AS Total
FROM t1 JOIN
     t2
     ON t2.id = t1.id
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (t1.continent, t1.country), (t1.continent) )
ORDER BY t1.continent,
         (CASE WHEN t1.country IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
         t1.country;
```

But it returns me this:

```
Continent | Country  | Bellow 45 yo | Above 45 yo | Total Habitants
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Europe    | Europe   |      1       |      1      |       2 
Europe    | England  |      0       |      1      |       1 
Europe    | Portugal |      1       |      0      |       1 
NA        | NA       |      2       |      1      |       3 
NA        | Canada   |      0       |      1      |       1 
NA        | USA      |      2       |      0      |       2
```

The original data is:

```
T1:                                   T2:
ID | Country  | Continent             ID | Name     | Age  | CountryID           
--------------------------            ---------------------------------
1  | England  | Europe                1  | Mary     | 67   |     1
2  | USA      | NA                    2  | Anthoine | 34   |     2
3  | Portugal | Europe                3  | Jorge    | 19   |     3
4  | Canada   | NA                    4  | Bella    | 46   |     4
                                      5  | Ana      | 26   |     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think you want:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN t1.Country IS NULL THEN t1.continent END) as Continent,       
       COALESCE(t1.country, t1.continent) as Country,
. . .
```

But why not just combine them into one column -- what is now your `country` column?

Comment: The code worked fine for the first part. But now I need to add a row at the end of the table showing the sum of every value above, something like there is in excel where you have `=SUM(A1:A20) ` for instance